# How append string to string in PHP based on an array of items

Tags: php, string, replace

I am trying to make a script to extend the view of the SQL returned by Zend and format this SQL code, so I'd like to insert "\n" to the reserved words of mysql and "\n" and "\t" to tables names, fields names, etc...

E.g( in short, I use more reserved words to match ):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = 'value';";
```

Output:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    field = 'value'
;
```

I could do a lot of calls to str_replace, but I need something like:

```
$sql = array('SELECT', 'FROM', 'WHERE', ... );
```

return "\nSELECT", "\nFROM", "\nWHERE" in the $sql variable.

The other characters I have already handled, the problems are the mysql reserved words

Any clue? I tried preg_replace but it still removes the matches.

Comment: What's your current `preg_replace()` code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$keywords = array(
    "select",
    "update"
); //etc
$sql = SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`field` = 'value';
$tokens = explode(" ", $sql);

foreach($tokens as $token)
    {

    // if token in $keywords print \n along with value else print as it is ..

    if (in_array($token, $keywords))
        {
        echo $token . "\n";
        }
      else
        {
        echo $token;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps ..